# Is there a way to set a custom font ot other stylings in Segmented Picker?

Tags: swiftui

I want to set some font styling in a Picker with SegmentedPickerStyle().
But any font formatting is ignored. Is there a way to set the font for a segmentedPicker?
I am pretty sure that it works for the default pickerWheel..

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport
import SwiftUI

 // Make a SwiftUI view
 struct ContentView: View {
  @State private var selection: Int = 2
     var body: some View {
      Picker("", selection: self.$selection) {
                    Text("Shape").tag(0)
                    Text("Height").tag(1)
        Text("Media").tag(2).font(.headline)
                    }
                      .font(.headline)
                      .cornerRadius(8)
                      .padding(10)
                      .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
     }
}

// Make a UIHostingController
let viewController = UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView())

// Assign it to the playground's liveView
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = viewController

// RUN!
```

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

SwiftUI uses UIKit (for iOS) under the hood, You should use appearance for `UISegmentedControl`:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    init() {
        UISegmentedControl.appearance().selectedSegmentTintColor = .red
        UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(
            [
                .font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 24),
                .foregroundColor: UIColor.white
        ], for: .selected)

        UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(
            [
                .font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 12),
                .foregroundColor: UIColor.blue
        ], for: .normal)
    }

    var body: some View { ,,, }
}
```

Comment: The customization of the UIKit component appearance should be done just once in the `AppDelegate`'s  `func application(_, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`

Comment: Who told that? It should be done where ever its needed ;)

Comment: That is not true @MojtabaHosseini, since it will update all UISegmentedControls, so it is a valid point to set it only once, on top level. If you only want to change a single segmented picker, this answer won't suffice

Comment: I agree to use it just once per changing entire app’s theme, but Who said that it should be on AppDelegate? It’s not a good practice

Comment: Certainly better than hiding it in a subview.

Comment: Definitely @iSpain17

Comment: Worth to mention that Apple makes no guarantee that a SwiftUI view is backed by the corresponding UIKit component. With iOS 14 we see this happening to List which decouples from UITableView, fwiw I would suggest wrapping the picker from UIKit if you need more control over the styling.